# WebSockets in kotlin

Tags: swift, sockets, kotlin

I want to establish a connection with a server. For the connection is established I need to pass a `url` and in `Header` the accessToken (I can do this). If the connection is make with successful i need to pass another value (`gameId`). In swift the solution pass for this way:

```
(...)

self.manager = SocketManager(socketURL: URL(string: K.ProductionServer.baseURL)!,
                                     config: [.log(true),
                                              .compress,
                                              .extraHeaders(["Authorization": "Bearer \(self.userSession.access_token)"]),
                                              .connectParams(["game_id": self.gameId])])

(...)
```

Is there anything like this in kotlin? Until now, I maked the code below.

```
private fun instantiateWebSocket() {
        val accessToken = "aaa"

        val client : OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()
        val request : Request = Request.Builder()
            .url("bbb")
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $accessToken")
            //.post("game_id", gameId)
            .build()

        val socketListener : SocketListener = SocketListener(this)
        webSocket  = client.newWebSocket(request, socketListener)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Ktor HTTP client](https://ktor.io/clients/index.html).